# HappyBase Table.cells not returning any result

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-python

Below is my code

```
# Create a Cloud Bigtable client.
client = bigtable.Client(project=config.GCP_PROJECT_ID)

# Connect to an existing Cloud Bigtable instance.
instance = client.instance(config.BIGTABLE_INSTANCE_ID)

# Open an existing table.
connection = Connection(instance=instance)
table = Table(name=config.BIGTABLE_TABLE_ID, connection=connection)

row_data = table.cells(row=row_key, column=column_family_id, include_timestamp=True)
print("test")
```

"Test" never printed. table.cells not returning any result. Does anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello-happybase provides an example via the HappyBase API, which may be helpful.

I would suggest checking if you have [set your Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials), and if you are able to get the instance and the table  successfully.